# Passing parameter to anonymous class in Java

Tags: java, parameter-passing, anonymous-class

i'm trying to write anonymous inner class

```
interface Face{
    void seeThis(String what);
}


class Eyes {
    public void show(Face f){}
}

public class Seen {

    public void test() {
        Eyes e = new Eyes();
        e.show(new Face() {

            @Override
            public void seeThis(String what){
                System.out.print(what);
            }
        });

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Seen s = new Seen();
        s.test();
    }
}
```

How to call seeThis() and how to pass parameter to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `seeThis()` belongs to `Face` class, which instance is anonymous and thus cannot be reached without storing reference to it. If you want to store a reference, you can do this in the following way:

```
public class Seen {
    public Face face;

    ....

    this.face = new Face() { ... };
    e.show(this.face);
```

And then,

```
Seen s = new Seen();
s.face.seeThis();
```

Now, regarding passing the parameter. You have two options - declare parameter outside of anonymous class and make it `final` in order to be reachable by this anonymous class, or replace anonymous class with normal one and pass the parameter to its constructor:

Approach one:

```
final int parameter = 5;

...(new Face() {
        @Override
        public void seeThis() {
            System.out.println(parameter);
        }
    });
```

Approach two:

```
public class MyFace implements Face() {
    private final int parameter;

    public MyFace(int parameter) {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    @Override
    public void seeThis() {
        System.out.println(parameter);
    }
}
```

Then,

```
...
e.show(new MyFace(10));
```

Comment: this statement s.face.seeThis() throw java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @EngMarwa Try to move `face = new Face()` into the constructor of `Seen`, or call `s.test()` before calling `seeThis()`.

Comment: @EngMarwa You're welcome. Do not forget to upvote and select the preferred answer as correct.